# htaccess RewriteRule declaration

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, unicode

I am using a htaccess file to make SEO friendly URL.

```
RewriteRule ^search/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+).html$ search-list.php?keyword=$1 [L]
```

But when my URL example.com/search/key_word_Mon%C3%A1e.html

Say Not found. i know there are unicode char in url so it is not working.

I am here to know how to declare a rule in ([A-Za-z0-9_-]+).html$ to make it functional with  unicode char.

I want to write a rule in ([A-Za-z0-9_-]+).html$ where i can supply anything in example.com/search/key_word_Mon%C3%A1e.html

This may be help >> http://unicode-table.com/en/

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the expression `([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)` to `([^/]+)` so that it will match against anything that isn't a slash.